# CefSharp Wpf WARNING:policy_logger.cc: Could not create policy manager as CBCM is not enabled

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I am creating a WPF Console app using CefSharp and more specifically a ChromiumWebBrowser in my MainWindow's XAML. During the `InitializeComponent()` I am receiving the following message
"[1106/121455.802:WARNING:policy_logger.cc(148)] :components\enterprise\browser\controller\chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(88) Could not create policy manager as CBCM is not enabled." which appears in the debbugging console each time my MainWindow window is activated. I know it is  just a warning, but how can I remove it? I am not using any cloud services.
Here is my MainWindow.xaml code for reference:

```
<Window x:Class="Manager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Manager"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Manager.WpfControls"
    xmlns:library="clr-namespace:Manager.library"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Manager 6.1" Height="768" Width="1024"
    WindowState="Normal"
    WindowStyle="None">
<Border BorderBrush="#8090aa" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="2">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser
             Grid.Row="1"
             x:Name="wb1"
             MinWidth="{Binding MinWidth}"
             Background="Transparent"
             Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
             Padding="0, 0, 0, 50"
             JavascriptMessageReceived="wb_PostMessage"
         />
         ...
     </Grid>
</Border>
```

I am targeting .NET 7.0 and
my CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore installer version is 117.2.40

I searched inside StackOverflow for all questions related to CBCM.
As I understood it seems that the problems might be related to some extensions (which sould be enabled by default). So a recommendation was to add some settings in the code-behind (CefSettings) with a flag of "disable-extensions", but I am not sure how to implement this in my case, as it should be done in the XAML code in my case, in order to avoid its appearance from the initialization time. And overall, I am not sure this will solve my problem at all.

Comment: You cannot set command line args in `xaml`. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/118/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/App.xaml.cs#L40 for an example of how I'd recommend setting args programatically.

Comment: Thanks, it was not directly applicable and did solve my problem, but it helped me hide the warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the problem, but the comment of [amaitland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4583726/amaitland) helped me hide the warnings in the log just by initializing the CefSharp before my `MainWindow`, thus on the `App` level.

I put it here in case somebody find it useful for him as well.

Here is the code I used:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
#if ANYCPU
            //Only required for PlatformTarget of AnyCPU
            CefRuntime.SubscribeAnyCpuAssemblyResolver();
#endif
            var settings = new CefSettings()
            {
                LogSeverity = CefSharp.LogSeverity.Error
            };
            if (!CefSharp.Cef.IsInitialized)
            {
                //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
                CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
            }
        }
    }
```